# How do I call the generate popup in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

There is a plugin for PhpStorm/IntelliJ that can generate a UUID and it says  "You will find it in the Generate popup -> Random UUID. "

Where is the "Generate Popup"?

Comment: `Code | Generate ...` ?? P.S. If you do not know where to find specific action or Settings/Preferences option -- try `Help | Find Action..` next time

Comment: @LazyOne I did. I searched every where I could think of before coming here. The only thing they have that's "Generate" is Alt + Insert, however that only generates a new file or directory. not like a code snippet or any kind of text.

Comment: @LazyOne here's an interesting discovery based on this conversation. since I set my keymap to Eclipse, there was a collision of hotkeys. I remapped this action and it works now.

Comment: `Alt+Insert` is the shortcut in Default keymap as well. And it works fine here on Windows 7. Just keep in mind that `File | New` also uses this shortcut ... so depending on where you will invoke it (inside Editor .. or in a Project View panel) it may bring different popup (e.g. `Code | Generate` is disabled if invoked from Project View or Structure panels ... but works just fine when Editor area is focused).

Answer (score 0):

`Code | Generate...`

NOTE: Make sure that Editor area is currently active, because this action is unavailable if focus is in Project View or Structure panel for example.

In Default keymap, both `Code | Generate` and `File | New` popups have the same shortcut -- depending what area is currently focused (e.g. aforementioned Editor or Project View) different popup will be shown.